# How to style tbody tr borders with CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So this is a plain [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah1Vm.png) tbody tr I'm using with React.

and I would like to style it like this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k08w.png)

The tree is pretty simple

```html
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>lendsqr</td>
                <td>{props.username}</td>
                <td>{props.email}</td>
                <td>{props.phoneNumber}</td>
                <td>{props.dateJoined}</td>
                <td>{props.status}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I've tried this and pretty much the same to tbody, tr

```css
tr  { 
    border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:gray;
}
```

the only one that works is td

```css
td  {
    border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
td  {
                border-width: 1px;
                border-style: none none solid;
                border-color: gray;
            }
```

The only way to style it is with td, if someone knows the why behind it I would love to know thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try giving margin-bottom, and margin-top to the td.

`td  {border-top:1px solid gray; border-bottom:1px solid gray }`